# Is the "data" attribute a standard attribute of the XHTML Strict Doctype?

Tags: xhtml, attributes, doctype

Like the title says, I'm trying to determine if `data` is a standard attribute in the XHTML strict doctype. I can't seem to find any information online (looks like its HTML-5ish).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about attributes with the `data-` prefix, that's indeed HTML5 only. If you want to use them in XHTML, you'd need XHTML5.

There is also an attribute whose name is just `data`. It's for `<object>` elements and works like the `src` attribute on images. It's part of HTML4 and XHTML1 in both Strict and Transitional doctypes.

Comment: it's HTML5 not XHTML5 HTML5 (purposefully) violates the XML specifications