# The "data" attribute in elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, xhtml

I don't have any trouble running my code. My question is: is this what I'm doing a good practice? Is this cross-browser/cross-platform compatible? 
I'm using xhtml strict doctype.

```
<div id="element" data='{"foo":"bar"}'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert($('#element').attr('data'));
</script>
```

Now you probably wonder why I'm not doing:

```
<div id="element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#element').data('json', '{"foo":"bar"}');
  alert($('#element').data('json'));
</script>
```

I give you an example why I'm doing so.
I'm loading all comments in one website with the default avatar image I want to load the right image only when the user scrolls down so I need to store somewhere the right image source.

```
<img id="avatar-1" src="default.png" data='{"src": "user-avatar.png"}' />
```

without this I need to do:

```
<img id="avatar-1" src="default.png" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#avatar-1').data('json', '{"src": "user-avatar.png"}');
</script>
```

And that produces dozens unnecessary script tags.
I know I can merge all these scripts in php and than display at once but the code will not be so readable like with the "data" solution.

If you know any better solution please let me know.

Answer (score 6):

As [parent5446 suggests in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534256/the-data-attribute-in-elements/4534318#4534318), the nice way to do this is with HTML5's custom data attributes.  These begin `data-` and can be used for your application's own purposes.  They will otherwise be ignored by the browser.

Even better, the most recent versions of jQuery will automatically load them into a [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) call, so you don't need to do a hacky call to [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

You could use the following HTML:

```
<img id="avatar-1" src="default.png" data-src="user-avatar.png" />
```

And then access it in the following way with jQuery:

```
alert($('#avatar-1').data('src'));
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason it seems the data attribute in the way you're using it simply does not exist. The only data attribute in XHTML is that of the  [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449662/is-the-data-attribute-a-standard-attribute-of-the-xhtml-strict-doctype). You might be talking about the custom [data tags in HTML5](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/customattributes.shtml). It is very well possible that jQuery is thinking your code is HTML5 and treating the data attributes as such, but I'm not too sure on that part.

Just adding from a comment on this question below, it turns out JavaScript has always been able to read arbitrary attributes, but it will not validate and some developers consider it bad form.

Comment: I also noticed that twitter is doing so

Comment: As the article you linked to points out, custom data tags have been readable in javascript forever. But it does throw a fit if you try to validate it and some developers (not inc myself) consider it bad form. HTML5 simply ignores anything preceded by `data-` meaning that you're not going to clash with a browser-specific attribute name by choosing a name like that and your pedantic colleagues have no more reason to complain.